# How to install bug fixes for nvidia in kernel 3.7.9?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, kernel, bumblebee

I am using Kernel 3.7.9 in Ubuntu 12.04. I currently can not build the Nvidia packages for Bumblebee.

There is a [bugfix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-updates/+bug/1075937) available, but I have no clue how to use it.

The instructions are:

```
[Impact] Nvidia and fglrx drivers need to be updated in order to build against Linux 3.7

[Test case]
1. Install the latest upstream kernel as described at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds
2. confirm that the nvidia and fglrx drivers fail to compile against this kernel, and that rebooting to this kernel gives no binary driver.
3. upgrade to the packages in precise-proposed.
4. confirm that the new version of the package successfully builds the kernel module.
```

The error:

```
Building initial module for 3.7.9-030709-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.7.9-030709-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.7.9-030709-generic (x86_64)
```

Would it be better to use another kernel version?

Comment: Why do you need Kernel 3.7.9? `precise-proposed` is not intended if you need a stable system.

Comment: I read somewhere that I need atleast 3.6+ for my laptop to run stable and http://kernel.org/ tells me that 3.7.9 is stable.

Comment: Where do you read that, source? What hardware do you have?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime They state that ubuntu 12.04 runs stable on my laptop. But at the bottom they tell me that most bug fixes are in 3.6+. But they also say that it is not recommended to upgrade 12.04 to a mainline kernel. I am a little bit confused. Would I be better of with 12.10?

Comment: If your systems runs fine with 12.04, then do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download `NVIDIA-x86_64-310-32.run` and execute: `./NVIDIA-x86_64-310-32.run --extract-only`.

Open file `./NVIDIA-x86_64-310-32/kernel/conftest.sh` and go to line 1706. Inside the test syntax for `SUBLEVEL` replace `$SUBLEVEL -le 5` by `$SUBLEVEL -le 9` and save the file.

Go to directory `./NVIDIA-x86_64-310-32/` and run `./nvidia-installer`. It will work correctly.

Enjoy

---

```
--- conftest.sh 2013-01-14 23:41:17.000000000 +0100
+++ conftest-patched.sh 2013-03-04 23:23:05.581357849 +0100
@@ -1703,7 +1703,7 @@
                 SUBLEVEL=$(grep "^SUBLEVEL =" $MAKEFILE | cut -d " " -f 3)

                 if [ -n "$PATCHLEVEL" -a $PATCHLEVEL -ge 6 \
-                        -a -n "$SUBLEVEL" -a $SUBLEVEL -le 5 ]; then
+                        -a -n "$SUBLEVEL" -a $SUBLEVEL -le 9 ]; then
                     SELECTED_MAKEFILE=Makefile.kbuild
                     RET=0
                 fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay on LTS you should try to install the hardware enablement stack, especially the kernel. You can install the quantal kernel via `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal` package, there is also a metapackage for the xserver. The raring kernel should be available in 12.04 shortly after the release of 13.04. Until then I recommend disabling the nvidia graphics, which isn't that bad because those Zenbooks all ship with latest Intel processors that feature Intel integrated graphics, which run almost flawless.

Comment: I am a graphics programmer and I need my nvidia gpu in order to use OpenGL 4.3 features. Should I better switch to 12.10?

Comment: I don't know the details about why the wiki page states that upgrading to a mainline version is not recommended. In your case installing or upgrading to 12.10 might be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try install the nvidia 313 driver. This will give you think I the best support for your linux version.

Do this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go to your additional driver page and select the nvidia 313 driver.
Wait until the driver is installed and reboot.

(srr about the dutch language screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more information, why this should solve the problem.

Comment: The newest driver should think i give you more support for newer linux kernels. I use this driver with 3.7.0-7-generic and it is the only that works properly.

Comment: @ThomasVanmellaerts - we are looking for a full step-by-step guide to help the OP and others searching for this question.  Please can you update your answer to provide this extra information.  Thanks.

Comment: I would have expected such information to be available at nvidias site http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-313.18-driver.html, but I forgot were talking about proprietary drivers of course.

Comment: Oke i would try, i thought that you only need to click on the correct driver in "proprietary drivers".

Comment: I have to use bumblebee because I have an optimus enabled gpu and I am not allowed to use official drivers for some reason.